# Disable scrolling on body in mobile safari, but allow in another div

Tags: ios, ipad, mobile, mobile-safari

So here's my predicament.

In mobile safari, `overflow:hidden;` doesn't work as it does on desktop. On desktop, adding this to the body disables scrolling in the browser, but then you can still scroll inside another div, say a drawer or a lightbox.

On mobile safari, you can still scroll the page with a touch and drag with your finger.

I came across a possible solution:

```
document.ontouchmove = function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

However, this disables scrolling altogether. Even in a drawer or lightbox div where I need to still allow scrolling.

I also came across another "fix" where people add `position:fixed;` to the body. This doesn't work in my scenario because the user could already be halfway down the page when they open a drawer/lightbox. This method would put the body in a fixed position, thus losing their scroll position of the body.

How can I disable any movement/scrolling of the body on mobile safari, but still allow scrolling in a drawer/lightbox?